# Show that if $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=-\infty$ than exist max ${a_n}$ (feedback required)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I am trying to proove that if $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=-\infty$ than max ${a_n}$ is exist. since we haven't studied any theorems about monotincaly sequences I was trying to do the following: (I would like your feedback)

From the given, I can choose $M=a_1$ and I know there exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t for every $n>n_0$ $$a_n<a_1$$ define the group $A$ s.t $A=\{a_i|1\leq i\leq n_0\}$ since this is a finite group of finite numbers, there exist $maxA=a_j $  for $1\leq j\leq n_0$from here we can say that for any $n$ $$a_n\leq a_j$$ the maximum of $a_n$ is recieved for $n=j$

Comment: That's fine. I suggest that you write “finite set” instead of “finite group” and that you simply write “numbers” instead of “finite numbers”.

Comment: Ok, I wrote to my self that note, thank you!